# Messed up something with Python 3/pip3/Miniconda 3 Installation and Linked Directories

Tags: raspbian, python, pip

So I'm not exactly sure what I did but I was trying to upgrade from Python 3.4.3 (Miniconda 3) to Python 3.8.x and somewhere along the way I ended up deleting a folder or symbolic link.

My main issue is that when running something like

***jupyter notebook*** from terminal I get ***bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory*** as a response

Additionally when I type in ***pip3 --version*** I get back ***bash: /usr/bin/pip3: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory***

I'd really just like to delete Python 3, pip3, Miniconda3, and any system links/Path links and restart from scratch. I am also fairly new to this type of issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are probably better off backing up any important files or data and reinstalling with a fresh SD card image. This kind of problem can lead to problems months into the future.

Comment: Thanks for the information, was hoping I wouldn't need to do that but oh well not much will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch.

You may be lucky and just be missing the symbolic link to /usr/bin/python3.7 as

```
/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.7
```

If not out of desperation you could try

`sudo apt install --reinstall xxx`

and try to get it to redo Python etc.  but I've never tried it on anything as vital as this though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I decided to just save anything important (wasn't much) and wipe the SD card and start fresh. Was a good excuse to try out a new OS also.